# JavaScript runtime error: query function not defined for Select2 undefined

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, jquery-select2

```
<select data-bind="select2: {}"></select>
<input data-bind="select2: {}">
```

if i use HTML **INPUT** with select2 and knockout within **foreach** binding with asp.net mvc i get this error in internet exploler

```
Unhandled exception at line 2890, column 21 in http://localhost:4052/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.debug.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: query function not defined for Select2 undefined
```

i get no error in mozilla and chrome, but they too dont behave as expected when i do this

```
<input data-bind="select2: {allowClear: true,placeholder: ' write tags here...', multiple: true, tokenSeparators: [',']}">
```

when i use `<select data-bind="select2: {}"></select>` i get no error even in IE...
basically, i want to have a tag input within the knockout auto-generated table that can do tagging like this...

```
$("#tags1,#tags2").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "Write Tags Here...",
    //createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {return {id:term, text:term};},
    //createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};} },
    multiple: true,
    tags: [],
    tokenSeparators: [","]
    //maximumInputLength: 15,
    //maximumSelectionSize: 5
    //data: [{id: 0, text: 'story', locked: true},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}]
});
```

i have used this custom bindings...
https://github.com/select2/select2/wiki/Knockout.js-Integration

Answer (score 0):

The way you are writing your custom handler/custom bindings is wrong,
Instead of `$("#tags1,#tags2").select2({})` 
it should be

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {}
```